# Is it a correct sentence ' met my friend over evening walk ' ? I thought met my friend on my evening walk was correct?

Tags: grammar

So today I heard someone say a sentence that didn't sound correct to me .
He said -

I met (friend's name) over evening walk today.

I think he should have said-

I met (friend's name) on my evening walk today .

Pls advise.
Thanks

Comment: Presumably your friend isn't a native Anglophone, We *might* say *I met him **over lunch***, but we wouldn't use ***over*** for an "evening walk" - that would have to be ***on*** or ***during*** (feasibly ***in*** or something else, but that's unlikely).

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers. Yes, it didn't sound correct to me and hence asked. So you agree that the correct way of saying this would be- I met (friend's name) on the evening walk today?

Comment: *...on **the** evening walk* is a bit odd - it *might* be "natural" in some contexts, but it would almost always be far better to say ***my** evening walk*.

Comment: _The evening walk_ presupposes a regular event, perhaps in both lives. _An evening walk_ doesn't say anything about regularity.

Comment: thanks for your reply @FumbleFingers

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JohnLawler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

"Walk" is countable, so you would need to say "*an* evening walk" (or "my evening walk").

"Over" in this sense is usually used with a meal or drink ("over lunch," "over a beer"). "On" or "during" is a more logical choice.

Comment: Thanks for explaining so well @alphabet

Comment: @Ritz Quite welcome! You can accept the answer if it's correct.